# Java 8 - how do I declare a method reference to an unbound non-static method that returns void

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, void, method-reference

Here's a simple class that illustrates my problem:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.function.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App a1 = new App();

        BiFunction<App, Long, Long> f1 = App::m1;
        BiFunction<App, Long, Void> f2 = App::m2;

        f1.apply(a1, 6L);
        f2.apply(a1, 6L);
    }

    private long m1(long x) {
        return x;
    }

    private void m2(long x) {
    }
}
```

`f1`, referring to `App::m1`, and being bound to `a1` in `f1`'s call to `apply`, works perfectly fine - the compiler is happy and the call can be made through f1.apply just fine.

`f2`, referring to `App::m2`, doesn't work.

I'd like to be able to define a method reference to an unbound non-static method with no return type, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: Yet another victim of `void != Void` :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`BiFunction` represents a function that accepts two arguments a*nd produces a result*.

> I'd like to be able to define a method reference to an unbound
>   non-static method with no return type

use a `BiConsumer` instead which represents an operation that accepts two input arguments *and returns no result*.

```
BiConsumer<App, Long> f2 = App::m2;
```

then change this:

```
f2.apply(a1, 6L);
```

to this:

```
f2.accept(a1, 6L);
```

Answer (score 3):

The method reference is App::m2, just like you have, but it's not assignable to a BiFunction, because it doesn't return a value, even a Void value (which has to be `null`). You'd have to do:

```
f2 = (a,b) -> { m2(a,b); return null; }
```

if you want a BiFunction. Alternatively, you could use a BiConsumer as mentioned in other answers.